# TradingView leftPriceScale Disappeared after scrolling

Tags: reactjs, tradingview-api

the view works good when not scrolling, but after scrolling, leftPriceScale is disappeared.

Before scrolling:

[image: beforeScrolling]

After scrolling:

[image: afterScrolling]

And Here's my config for init.

```
createChart(container, {
        width: chartSize.current.width,
        height: chartSize.current.height,
        leftPriceScale: {
          visible: true,
          borderVisible: false,
        },
        rightPriceScale: {
          visible: false,
        },
        timeScale: {
          visible: true,
          borderVisible: true,
        },
        layout: {
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
          textColor: '#fff',
        },
        grid: {
          horzLines: {
            color: 'transparent',
          },
          vertLines: {
            color: 'transparent',
          },
        },
        localization: {
          locale: 'en-US',
        },
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!
add Logarithmic mode in leftPriceScale obj like this

```
     leftPriceScale: {
          visible: true,
          borderVisible: false,
          mode: PriceScaleMode.Logarithmic,
        },
```